# drawing textures on live wallpaper using OpenGL in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, live-wallpaper

Hii,

I want to make a simple live wallpaper using OpenGL in Android that will draw the textures.

I have develop a simple OpenGL Activity that can work exactly for live wallpaper. But some problems are there like IllegleArgumentException.

I am using GLWallpaperService from earth live wallpaper.

Thanks....

Answer (score 2):

You may have better luck getting GLWallpaperService from [the main project repository on github](https://github.com/GLWallpaperService/GLWallpaperService). It is actively maintained and documented there.

Modern releases of GLWallpaperService will accept a GLSurfaceView.Renderer class. This means you can reuse the Renderer class that you wrote for your activity directly in your live wallpaper.

Answer (score 1):

i've done the same task today.

it can be useful for you:
http://www.rbgrn.net/content/354-glsurfaceview-adapted-3d-live-wallpapers

Comment: Please do not use the GLWallpaperService at the rbgrn.net link, as it is now outdated. Years ago, I copied the rbgrn.net code with permission and started improving it. The latest code is available at https://github.com/GLWallpaperService/GLWallpaperService